# Sequential Clicks with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to click a button, which acts as a toggle, for a Boolean value.

When this value is true, I'd like to be able to click anywhere on the page and capture the ID of the parent div for the element clicked.

The toggle is easy, but I have no idea how to do the second part.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var booleanValue = false;
$("button").click(function(){
   booleanValue = !booleanValue;
});

$(document).click(function(e)
{
   if(booleanValue ){
       //If the parent element of the element clicked(e.target) is not a div then
       //closest will make sure to find the nearest div
       alert($(e.target).parent().closest('div').attr('id'));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on Rionmonster's solution:

```
var getIdBoolean = true;  
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if (getIdBoolean)
       $target = $(e.target);
       alert($target.parent().attr("id"));
 }
```

Read all about it: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0):

You could just bind click-event on the body with a event in the method and look after the event.target:

```
$(function() {
    var toggle = false;
    var button = $("#toggleButton").click(function() {
        toggle = !toggle;

        $("body")[toggle ? 'bind' : 'unbind']("click.parentId", function(function(e) {
            var target = $(e.target);
            //Your what you want to do with your target...
        });
    });
});
```

something like that?